# Golang time zone list

Tags: go, time, timezone

Does anyone know of a way to have Go's time package (https://golang.org/pkg/time/) provide me with a list of valid Locations (aka valid time zones)? I'm writing an application and I'd like to present users with a valid list of time zones based on the ones that will work with Go. However, based on my study of the package, it doesn't seem like any such list is available from an exported func or variable.

I do know that Go uses the IANA Time Zone Database as its underlying supplier of time zone info, and I can get my own copy of the database to extract the information that I need. It just seems like it would be easier if I could get the list from Go since it already has access for that information without me having to write my own code to parse the IANA Time Zone Database.

Comment: You do need the time zone database, but you don't have to write the parsing logic for it. You may use [`time.LoadLocationFromTZData()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocationFromTZData). Also see unexported [`time/zoneinfo_abbrs_windows.go`](https://golang.org/src/time/zoneinfo_abbrs_windows.go) which is generated by [`time/genzabbrs.go`](https://golang.org/src/time/genzabbrs.go).

Comment: @icza I do not understant how that works, how do I get "data" parameter, could you make an example please, I'm having trouble with container aplication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489347/how-to-create-a-binary-that-contains-zoneinfo-zip

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias you can see example in https://golang.org/src/time/zoneinfo.go

Comment: @Gintama I just did it by the time a post my comment, but thanks anyway :D