# InfluxDB Time Zone issue?

Tags: timezone, influxdb

influxDB 1.7.7 version has a bug with time zone implementation. So I searched from Google, the reason was GO language installation for Windows. I found that I have to place zoneinfo.zip (Go folder) folder into the somewhere, but I don't know where, which place? Has anybody dealt with it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489347/how-to-create-a-binary-that-contains-zoneinfo-zip

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Firstly you have to download Go language. Remove all except lib folder which has time zone zip file (zoneinfo.zip). Then follow instructions below.

Install instructions for Windows (verified):

1.) Copy-paste Go folder into your desired path.

2.) Add followings into the System Enviroment Variable:
    variable name: GOROOT 
    variable  value: path of copied Go folder